# How much tables are enough in single database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website as a blog in `PHP` using `MySQL` database server. In this website I also allow to user to create their own blog. When a user create a new blog in my website it adds **5 new tables** in the same database so that on creation of each blog it will add 5 new tables for each blog and so on.

***So my question is*** to know if the tables limit will reach over the 1,000 within the same database, will it disturb the overall performance of my website or it will be OK in this way?

Comment: Why not store all users data in only 5 tables with their use rid.  why you create 5 tables each time?

Comment: Creating new table set for each user doesn't sound scalable. Take a look at how Wordpress is laid out. https://www.sitepoint.com/the-wordpress-database-demystified/ But in simple terms, you can maintain a users table and a posts table, and join on account id.

Comment: because I want to separate the posts content and do not want to store the data in one table.

Comment: @Jameson do you think according to your experience this is not a good idea?

Comment: @FahadKazmi Yea, the main issue is that you'd no longer have a well-defined database schema -- instead of having a fixed, known number of tables, you have a dynamic collection of tables. Definitely the standard approach to this problem is to have one table to model per data type, and then join on some field. In this case, you can join user data with post data based on account id (so long as you include both of those columns in each table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitout issue abot server config or performance

You can take a look at mysql Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html

> C.10.2 Limits on Number of Databases and Tables
>
> MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file
>   system may have a limit on the number of directories.
>
> MySQL has no limit on the number of tables. The underlying file system
>   may have a limit on the number of files that represent tables.
>   Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints.
>   InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.

Comment: So this can be good idea according to website performance creating additional tables for each blog in my website as this is needed?

Comment: Yes  ..for performance  is better have more table with few rows  respect few tables  with many rows .. some db designer use also  separated db .. . tipically the multitenancy db design use separated set of similar tables

Comment: Thank to you ... i have designed  several database for  multitenancy application  and the pattern for repeated  schema  It has always proved very useful